# Linq - filter list

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-objects

I am building a simple search tool in vb.net windows forms application with sql server database, 
The user will enter a unique id and will see the results which shows the status.

### Object Class:

```
            Public Class IStatus
                    Public Property Id As String
                    Public Property Status As String

                    Public Sub New(ByVal Id As String, ByVal Status As String)
                        Id = Id
                        Status = Status            
                    End Sub
            End Class
```

What I am doing is populate the rows from the database in a List(Of IStatus)
Now I want to filter the rows using linq from a datatable, so far I have done the following:

```
            Public Function GetDS() As List(Of IStatus)
                    Dim sRows As New List(Of IStatus)
                    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = GetDataReader()
                    If dr.HasRows Then
                        Using dt As New DataTable
                            dt.Load(dr)
                            totRows = dt.Rows.Count
                            If (totRows > 1) Then
                                For Each drow As DataRow In dt.Rows
                                    Dim sRow As New IStatus(drow(0).ToString(), drow(1).ToString())
                                    sRows.Add(sRow)
                                Next

                                'Trying to filter the data with linq conditions here ... 
                                Dim uniqRows = sRows.Where(Function(p) p.Status = "Open" Or p.Status = "Closed" Or p.Status = "Unknown").ToList
                                sRows = uniqRows.ToList
                            Else
                                Dim sRow As New IStatus(dt.Rows(0)(0).ToString, dt.Rows(0)(1).ToString)
                                sRows.Add(sRow)
                            End If
                            Return sRows
                        End Using
                    End If
            End Function
```

I have a list of the following object:

```
IStatus
-----------
Id
Status
```

Following is the sample data and the filtering I am looking to achieve:

Eg Data:

```
-----------------
Id           Status
-----------------
1            Open
1            Open
1            Closed
```

Return all the rows as one of status value is different.

```
Id           Status
-----------------
1            Open
1            Open
1            Open
```

Return just the first row as all the status values are same.

```
Id           Status
-----------------
1            Unknown
1            Open
1            Open
```

Return the Unknown row if any one of the status is Unknown.

Thanks.

Comment: And what is your question? What did you try to solve this issue? We´re not doing your work here. Apart from this: why tga a question which specifically asks for VB.NET with C# also?

Comment: Why has everything got the ID of 1, i am struggling to make sense of this, also post your code

Comment: Also choose a language and remove the ones you are not using from the tags

Comment: Hi, I am new to linq, and would like to learn the same in c# too. so I tagged both vb.net and c#

Comment: Id will not always be 1, there are multiple rows in the table with this id as key field. From the database I am filtering this with id

Comment: This reads like it's your homework assignment. Which might not be bad, it's just that we don't do that here. We help people with specific problems *they have* while solving their problems. So give it a try, and if it does not work as expected, provide us with an [MCVE] and a clear problem description. If you don't know how to start, then you need to find a good book or tutorial, that kind of help is too broad to fit into a post here.

Comment: Hi, updated my question with the code that I have done so far...

Comment: @nvoigt  have updated my question with more details, hope to get an answer.... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the findall function to filter a generic list

```
Public Class IStatus
    Public Property Id As String
    Public Property Status As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal Id_ As String, ByVal Status_ As String)
        Id = Id_
        Status = Status_
    End Sub
End Class
Function Createlist() As List(Of IStatus)
    Dim L1 = New List(Of IStatus)()
    L1.Add(New IStatus("1", "open"))
    L1.Add(New IStatus("1", "open"))
    L1.Add(New IStatus("1", "closed"))
    L1.Add(New IStatus("1", "closed"))
    L1.Add(New IStatus("1", "closed"))
    L1.Add(New IStatus("2", "open"))
    L1.Add(New IStatus("2", "open"))
    L1.Add(New IStatus("2", "closed"))
    L1.Add(New IStatus("2", "closed"))
    L1.Add(New IStatus("2", "closed"))
    Return L1
End Function
Sub main()
    Dim l1 = Createlist().FindAll(Function(x As IStatus) x.Id = "1")
    For Each ii In l1
        With ii
            Console.WriteLine(.Id & "- " & .Status)
        End With

    Next
    Stop
End Sub
```